# Python script for adding Child Of bone constraint with 'Set Inverse' to multiple bones?

Tags: python, scripting, bones

Completely new to scripting and was hoping someone would help me out here.

I've imported a rig twice and want to add a "Child Of" bone constraint to each bone in the first rig using the matching bone in the second rig as the target. I also want to use "Set Inverse" function of this constraint.

[image]

The rigs are the same, so all the bones are named the same.

Rigs are called "root" and "root.001".

I figure I need to do something with:

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

rig1 = scene.objects.get("root")
rig2 = scene.objects.get("root.001")

for bone in rig1.pose.bones:
    cbone = bone
    cbname = bone.name
    setchild = bone.constraints.new(type='CHILD_OF')
    setchild.target = rig2
    setchild.subtarget = cbname
```

But beyond that I have no clue. I'm not sure how to set the inverse option.

I'm looking to edit a number of animation files, so would need to do this process for each fbx file, and therefore would love to automate the process.

Hoping someone can help me out.
Cheers.

Comment: Hi. There is no property called 'inverse' that can be set. That makes no sense. Could you clarify?

Comment: Basically looking to do this: https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/animation/86629-blender-auto-bone-orientation

In relation to the set inverse, I'm talking about when you add a constraint in pose mode to set a parent bone you have the option of clicking "set inverse" so the child keeps it's original position.(https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/child_of.html)

Seems to be "bpy.ops.constraint.childof_set_inverse()" ? But Again, I don't know anything about Python.

Comment: OK, that makes sense then. You are talking about Child Of object constraint, not parenting. There is a difference.

Comment: Or is it bone constraint, not object constraint?

Comment: I'm assuming bone constraint? It's done in Pose mode?

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edit.

Comment: Definitely not! Cheers.

Comment: I thought I would help with writing the script, but I have little experience with bones and their constraints as I never have to work with rigging and animations. Hopefully you will get some help from someone more experienced in this area.

Comment: check [link](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/solved-set-inverse-child-of-constraints-via-python/3050/5) seems to perform what you are looking for. If this is what you need it may be worthwhile to add it as your own answer and include link to original poster.

Answer (score 1):

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.active_object

# Take a copy of current layers 
org_layers = ob.data.layers[:]

# Show all layers
for i in range(len(org_layers)):
    ob.data.layers[i] = True

for b in ob.pose.bones:
    for c in b.constraints: 
        if c.type == "CHILD_OF":
            context_py = bpy.context.copy()
            context_py["constraint"] = c
            ob.data.bones.active = b.bone
            bpy.ops.constraint.childof_set_inverse(context_py, constraint="Child Of", owner='BONE')

# Reset back to orginal layer state    
for i in range(len(org_layers)):
    ob.data.layers[i] = org_layers[i]
```

Found by Ratt, cheers guys! (let me know if this is what you meant)!